# Line texture becomes a solid colour when switching to cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, uv, eevee-render-engine, transparency

In the Eevee renderer and in the material preview, the texture seems normal but when I change to cycles, the texture becomes a solid colour. Here is before: [image]

And here after: [image]

And the texture looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone help? Thank you.

Comment: Hello. Could you add a picture of the shader node tree?

Comment: @lemon https://ibb.co/1Z2CJcg

Comment: That does not help so much (for me). Can you upload a file with the glass part (with textures packed)? Please use this http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the obtained link here.

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=XxsDgPLr" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/XxsDgPLr/)

Comment: I don't get this. I tried doing it on the glass file and it worked but not on the initial model (??)

Comment: Yes I've just seen that. Maybe there is another object that reflects on the glass?

Comment: There are several glasses (five), is that wanted?

Comment: There are only supposed  to be 3

Comment: I also found out that in the original model, there was a some sort of duplicate texture that I can't seem to get rid of. I tried unlinking some textures, deleting meshes but nothing worked.

Comment: Forget it about the five: yes three... There is custom normals, you can try to clear them (not significant with the glass alone). Or upload all the model?

Comment: Because blend exchange only supports files under 30mb, I sent you a google drive link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/11ry3ZTUw0gL5WabFRbjd1mV5ItkT0H24/view?usp=sharing

Comment: What? Ok, I downloaded Google Drive and it randomly fixed itself :/

Comment: I see... that will stay a mystery, maybe : )

Comment: Though, there is effectively 4 parts for the glass this time.